# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, undefined

Hello I'm a beginner of react, I'm stuck Cannot read the property 'map' of undefined, I understand is a type error please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Message from "./Message";


class MessageList extends Component {
    render() {
        const   { messages } = this.props;
        return messages.map(message => (
            <ul>
                <Message message={message} />
            </ul>
        ));
    }   
}

export default MessageList;
```

Comment: messages can be a null, so you need to check if messages is null.
messages && messages.map(...)

Comment: Console.log messages like this: console.log('messages: ', messages)

Comment: Check whether you are passing `messages` to `MessageList` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To u can try to use the "null object” pattern to avoid such errors when the prop is not uet to be sent to the component, the issue is not coming from the code you showed us so we cant help you find the main problem

Null object pattern Inside of the render method (also in this case is a default param):

```
const   { messages = [] } = this.props;
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested messages can be null in which case map will throw an error.
However, you also haven't constructed props which means messages will always be null.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Message from "./Message";


class MessageList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // state if you need it.
   this.state = { counter: 0 };
 }
    render() {
        const   { messages } = this.props;
        return messages && messages.map(message => (
            <ul>
                <Message message={message} />
            </ul>
        ));
    }   
}

export default MessageList;
```

Tested and this works.